# Saving Score in a Label and loading when the app opens

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, nsuserdefaults

I'm setting up a "click counter" on my iOS app, so the user will know how many times he performed an action. I'm using NSUserDefaults, for I'm can't make it load when the app opens.

First I created a UILabel that stores the number and increases it each time the user click on it:

```
 - (IBAction) increaseScore {
self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 1;
currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", self.currentScore];

 // Saving:

  NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:currentScoreLabel.text forKey: @"Score"];
  [defaults synchronize]; }
```

This works OK, the Label increases +1 each time I click on the button. Not sure if it is saving correctly, because when I close the app opens again, it doesn't load, the label goes back to zero:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

currentScoreLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"Store"];
}
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got a typo there. In your increaseScore method you're setting an object for key "Score" and in your viewDidLoad you're trying to get a string for key "Store". Bummer but I always try to setup up a static NSString of they keys I'm using for this exact reason. Ex:

```
static NSString* kScoreKey = @"Score";
```

this way you call

```
[defaults setObject:currentScoreLabel.text forKey:kScoreKey];
```

and

```
currentScoreLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kScoreKey];
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked. But I gave a different problem, when the app opens it loads the info and the score, but even if the score is 15, when I press the button it goes back to 1 instead of 16. :/

Comment: That's because it's no longer in memory when the app launches from simulator. Put this in your viewDidLoad. currentScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Store"] integerValue];